# why it is saying at i have declare kernel

Tags: python, numpy

```
    import numpy as np
    from numpy.fft import fft2, ifft2
    import cv2
    from PIL import Image
    def wiener_filter(img,kernel,K = 10):
        kernel=([3,1],[2,1])
        dummy = np.copy(img)
        kernel = np.pad(kernel, [(0, dummy.shape[0] - kernel.shape[0]), (0, dummy.shape[1] - kernel.shape[1])], 'constant')
        # Fourier Transform
        dummy = fft2(dummy)
        kernel = fft2(kernel)
        kernel = np.conj(kernel) / (np.abs(kernel) ** 2 + K)
        dummy = dummy * kernel
        dummy = np.abs(ifft2(dummy))
        return np.uint8(dummy)

    img = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\anup\\Desktop\\New folder\\leo.jpg")
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(gray,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
    kernel=([3,1],[2,1])
    fm = wiener_filter(img,kernel)
    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I am trying to implement the Wiener Filter to perform deconvolution on blurred image. My implementation is like this

While implementing this i got error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\deblur.py", line 21, in <module>
    fm = wiener_filter(img,kernel)
  File "C:\Python27\deblur.py", line 8, in wiener_filter
    kernel = np.pad(kernel, [(0, dummy.shape[0] - kernel.shape[0]), (0, dummy.shape[1] - kernel.shape[1])], 'constant')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Comment: You are reusing the variable `kernel` a lot here, try to not clobber that name.

Comment: It's saying that how you defined `kernel` is not compatible with how you are trying to use it. You made a tuple, but are using it as though it were an array.

Comment: now i am getting error as kernel is not defined...Actually i am trying to deblur the image

Answer (score 2):

There :

```
def wiener_filter(img,kernel,K = 10):
    kernel=([3,1],[2,1])
```

You define a function that takes `kernel` as a parameter and you overwrite it directly.

Then you try to use `kernel.shape` which obviously doesn't exist in `([3,1],[2,1])`

Apparently, `shape` is a method used for `numpy` `ndarray` objects.
So maybe this works for you :

```
def wiener_filter(img,kernel,K = 10):
    kernel=np.array([[3,1],[2,1]])
```

Or as mentionned by @Eric :

```
def wiener_filter(img,kernel,K = 10):
    kernel=np.array(kernel)
```

Comment: Better to just do `kernel = np.asarray(kernel)`, and then stick to passing in the kernel

Comment: from PIL import Image
def wiener_filter(img,kernel,K = 10):
    kernel=np.array([[0,1,0],[1,-4,1],[0,1,0]]) but i m getting errorTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\deblur.py", line 21, in <module>
    fm = wiener_filter(img,kernel)
  File "C:\Python27\deblur.py", line 13, in wiener_filter
    dummy = dummy * kernel
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (121,161,3) (121,161)

Comment: @anupchoudhary This is another question, and I don't know the answer to this one. You should probably create a new one.

Comment: can u give me suggestion how to deblur the image..it will be helpful if u provide me code..